# Freebase find all bands from an artist?

Tags: google-api, freebase, google-api-client, mql

If I have a band member, mid: "/m/0411131" (in this case Jack Barakat from All Time Low.

How do I find all the bands he's been in using freebase.search or mql?

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
            {
              "name": [],
              "type|=": [
                "/music/artist",
                "/music/musical_group"
              ],
              "/music/musical_group/member": [{
                "member": "Jack Barakat"
              }]
            }
```